# Failed to connect a SQL Server 2008 Database to Android application

Tags: sql, database, sql-server-2008, android-studio

I want to connect a SQL server 2008 R2 management studio "database" to an Android mobile application.  I used a demo application from this site: 
http://seotoolzz.com/android/android-login-app-with-mssql-server.php

i changed these:

ip = "192.168.1.105"; // my laptop ip

db = "AURAK"; //my database name

un = "AD"; //my laptop name

pass = "123"; //my laptop pass

Note that: i don't have a server so i am trying to connect my local PC to my android phone in the same network. I have downloaded the drive and build the gradle on my project

[image]

And here how my database looks like:
[image]

**My question is: After trying all of this, it is not working.  I have been trying other applications & Online databases, but nothing works. Can someone tell me where did i make a mistake here or point me for a solution?**

**Thanks.**

Comment: Have you configured sql server on your laptop to accept remote connections?

Comment: @Jayvee I went to the SQL configuration management and enabled TCP/IP connection if that what u mean. Still not working.

Comment: yes, you also need to open a port in the firewall; this is a god step by step guide https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/walzenbach/2010/04/14/how-to-enable-remote-connections-in-sql-server-2008/

Comment: @Jayvee  I already did that. Didn't work.